# Is new Order management part of commerce cloud only?

Tags: order

I tried to access Order Management App in my Salesforce org, but I can not see the same. Does it come with commerce cloud only?.
If we do not have commerce cloud, can't we access Order management console defined by salesforce at below url?
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/om-salesforce-order-management/om-get-started-order-management

Please note that we have already activated order in setup and we can see order object already, but not order management app.

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Orgs created after February 2020 will automatically have Salesforce Order Management provisioned and yes Order Management is designed to connect and automate the whole order process through Salesforce Commerce Cloud.

Please follow below to create a new Salesforce Order Management enabled Org

- 1. Create a new Developer Org  2) Enable Person Accounts in the organization 3) Enable My Domain

Once these steps are completed, you will have a Developer org with the basic requirements to follow the [Salesforce Order Management Implementation Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.om_order_management.htm&type=5)

Thanks

Comment: I just created a new Partner Developer Edition org and it doesn't have Order Management app, however, I can enable it in usual Developer Edition org...